# Getting no return

Tags: php

The following code returns "works",
but nothing else. Is there something I'm missing?
I've been looking and trying different things for 3 days, and nothing I have tried seems to work.
I'm running sql server express 2012 and Webmatrix 3.

```
<?php
$serverName = "UA-TSS-HA\SQLEXpress";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"stamping");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connecctionOptions);

if($conn)
{
    echo"works";
}
else
{
    echo"fails";
}
$sql = "SELECT fName, lName, age FROM names";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "Person =" . $row["fName"]. "" .["lName"]. "" .["age"]. "</br>";
    }
}else{
    echo"0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: you're mixing MySQL APIs here.

Comment: plus, look at these 2 variables `$connectionOptions` and `$connecctionOptions` if that isn't a typo.

Comment: comment fix *"you're mixing MySQL APIs here"* which should have read as "you're mixing SQL/connection APIs here". Visit http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php they're showing different function names than what you are using right now.

Comment: Ditto what @Fred-ii- is saying here. You should connect to SQL Server using PDO, then you can use the functions you're using. There are probably tons of errors in your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [`sqlsrv_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) connection method, but not using the proper functions in your query being the `mysqli_` libraries functions:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

For example:

- `query()` should be `sqlsrv_query(...)`
- `num_rows` should be `sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt)`
- `fetch_assoc()` should be `sqlsrv_fetch_array(...)`
- `close()` should be `sqlsrv_close(resource $conn)`

This taken from the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

Or using the PDO driver/library:

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Thank you all for your help and the good references. I was able to get it to do what I wanted from the start.

Comment: @HeathAtchley You're welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*